# Adding more data to one user in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, models

I have a edit profile page in Vake project profile.ctp that uses profileController?
I want to add input field for urls, phones etc but user can have more phones so I created another table called users_phones

```
USERS_PHONES
id
user_id
phone
```

in my view I created the form

```
<?
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('UsersPhones.phone');
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

and in model I have:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Phones' => array(
        'className'     => 'UsersPhones',
        'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
        'dependent'     => true
    )
);
```

controller:

```
$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => false))) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Profile updated succsessefully!',
                                        'default', array('class' => 'okmsg'));

    $this->redirect($this->request->here);
    } else {
$this->Session->setFlash('Profile could not be saved. Please, try again.',
                                                    'default', array('class' => 'errormsg'));
}
}
```

but when I click SAVE it wont insert into users_phones

Comment: why is there no create() call before your save() or saveAll()? This is necessary if you want to insert instead of update.

Comment: [See this please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422670/cakephp-associations-error-wont-save-associated-table)

Comment: he is no better ;) working or not (and it actually might if you haven't used the model so far), you need to use create() if you want to insert data.

Comment: But if user create it and next time he want to update? How to do that?

Comment: ah, so this is an edit page? have you passed the id of the record, as well? from the look at your form it doesnt seem like it.

Comment: I passed the user id
$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
First line in controller

Comment: You should add it to the data array `$this->request->data['User']['id'] = $uid;` before calling saveAll()

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace save() with saveAll() (or saveAssociated/saveMany) that supports saving multiple data.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: It won't save!
Check again naming conventions? Is it OK?
database: user_phones
$hasMany = array('UserPhones');
and input in UserController
$this->Forms->input('UserPhones.phone')
Did I made mistake somewhere?

Comment: If it doesnt save, check on `$this->User->validationErrors` - it must contain the errors.

Comment: No there's no error it gives me successful message but not save.
[see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422670/cakephp-associations-error-wont-save-associated-table)