# CakePHP Associations error? Won't save associated table

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, associations, model-associations

I created a user profile where users can add their information. So on URL section I want them to put their other links like Facebook, www.facebook.com/user etc.

But when I click Save nothing updates?

Here is the Model for User:
Models/User.php

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';

    public $hasMany = array (
    'UserWeb'=>array(
        'className'=>'UserWeb',
        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

The model for UserWeb:
Models/UserWeb.php

```
<?php
class UserWeb extends AppModel {

public $name = 'UserWeb';

public $belongsTo = array('User' =>
    array('className'  => 'User',
        'conditions' => '',
    'order'      => '',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    )
    );
}
?>
```

The controller for user:

```
$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => false))) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Profile updated succsessefully!',
                                     'default', array('class' => 'okmsg'));

    $this->redirect($this->request->here);
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash('Profile could not be saved. Please, try again.',
                                       'default', array('class' => 'errormsg'));
    }
}
```

And the View form:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('UserWeb.title',
         array('label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Title'));
echo $this->Form->input('UserWeb.url',
         array('label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Enter URL'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

Can Anyone help please? I'm trying to find solution for a lot of time.
When I submit the form it won't store new informations in user_webs table.

And btw here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_webs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `web` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `web` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to Associated model's data. And your primary Model does not have data to save.

You can take two approaches here,

1. Your present way, take `User`'s info and have them provide `UserWeb` information from the same form. The use will provide the information as a part of registration. For this you should refer to [Saving Associated model data - saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array)
2. Second way, have user provide their info during registration and let them add `UsersWeb` later. (by later I mean user's can update it during registration as well but not in same form). For this use `UserWeb`. Have the same form appear from `/yourapp/UsersWebs/add`. You will have to provide the `user_id`. This will be more refined.

P.S: I strongly recommend you to go through [Saving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-your-data) again. It will hardly take you 10 mins, I am sure you have done this before but sparing another 10 mins after having encountered the issue will help you understand these things as back of your hand.